# Regex: Is it possible to skip repeating negative lookbehinds?

Tags: java, regex

I've been trying to fix a simple regex that:

1. **Matches all characters from beginning of line (`^`) to the first `&` character *or* to the end of line (`$`).**
2. **The match cannot start with a `&`.**

Examples:

1. **`test` should match `test`.**
2. **`one&two` should match `one`.**
3. **`&test` shouldn't match anything.**

My current regex is the following:

```
^(?<!\&)(.+?)(?=\&|$)
```

([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xZ1gL8/5))

---

Currently, this regex fails example 3, where if I gave this regex `&test` it matches `&test`, but it shouldn't match anything.

I think it may be a problem with the negative lookbehind `(?<!\&)` and that `&test` matches because the character before it is not a `&`, but it doesn't account for any following `&` characters.

Is modifying the negative lookbehind to account for repeating `&` characters possible, and if so, how could I fix this regex?

---

(I know that Regex101 is using Python's Regex, but this question's Regex is intended to work with Java.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a look-ahead instead of a look-behind, and instead of lazy dot matching with a lookahead, use a negated character class:

```
^[^&]+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aU0mI2/4) (note that `\n` is added just for a demo, if you test strings without newline characters, it won't be necessary).

Here, `^` asserts the position at the start of the string, and `[^&]+` class matches 1 or more characters other than `&` (thus, no need to use `(?=\&|$)` look-ahead, if needed, the whole line will be matched).

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/iz9tGu)

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println(fetchMatch("test", 0));
    System.out.println(fetchMatch("one&test", 0));
    System.out.println(fetchMatch("&test", 0));
}
public static String fetchMatch(String s, int groupId)
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[^&]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()){
        return matcher.group(groupId); 
    } 
    return "ERROR: NOT MATCHED";
}
```

Output:

```
test
one
ERROR: NOT MATCHED
```

Comment: ah, a negative character class, how could i have not known such a thing existed?

Comment: Actually, true @RealSkeptic. It is already forbidden. My brains now work as linearly as a regex engine :) If we keep `(.+?)`, then the `(?!&)` is required. That was what I meant.